# I am not able to pass bamboo variables in build.xml . What is missing?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration

I have declared global variable in bamboo as

`sf_username` and `sf_password`

This is my job (ANT job in bamboo) :-

```
 deployCode -Dsfdc.username = ${bamboo.sf_username} -Dsfdc.password = ${bamboo.sf_password}
```

and this is build.xml (part where I declare deployCode)

```
<target name="deployCode" depends="proxy">


      <sf:deploy
        username="${sfdc.username}"
        password="${sfdc.password}"         
        serverurl="${sfdc.serverurl}"
        deployRoot="${basedir}/src"
        pollWaitMillis="${sfdc.pollWaitMillis}"
        maxPoll="${sfdc.maxPoll}"
        runAllTests="false" />
    </target>
```

I think , I have followed the documentation but still not able to pass global variables when I run ANT job. What is my mistake ? Any help please..

log when i echo

```
02-Jul-2015 11:45:24    deployCode:
02-Jul-2015 11:45:24         [echo] Performing the deploy XXXXX
02-Jul-2015 11:45:24         [echo] **${sfdc.passowrd}** and mnimbal@xxx.com.xxx
```

Comment: whats the error thats showing ?Are you able to login to SFDC via bamboo?

Comment: I did all the while by hardcoding my values in build.properties. But this time I wanted them to be saved in bamboo. Bamboo does hit test.salesforce.com. but errors out as invalid username and password. I am sure username is right and password is right too. ( i don't need security token). Since it is not able to access variables it is erroring out this way

Comment: if you see the echo logs it does access username properly. Its password thats causing issue

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with Azure DevOps. How did you manage to bypass the build.properties file? Even though my Ant script correctly recognizes my variables I declared, I still need to manually enter the credentials in the build.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer ... someone teach me English!

> password != passowrd

it's a typo in build.xml and I spent all morning fixing it.

P.S.  ( I have updated the question so typo is corrected).

Comment: nice !! Glad you nailed it :)

Comment: PS:+1 for both question and ans